# Consulta SQL con "left join" y un "if" en PHP

Tags: php, sql, join

Tengo esta consulta:

```
$customers_query_raw = "select ex.codigo_op, ep.entrega01_clave, ep.descripcion_articulo, ep.entrega01_envases, ep.entrega01_importe from " . TABLE_EXPORT_PATRIMONIO . " ep left join " . TABLE_EXPORT_COMPARATIVA_PATRI . " ex on ex.clave_patri = ep.entrega01_clave where ep.entrega01_envases <> '' and ep.num_envases <> '0' and ep.entrega01_indicaciones = 'null'";
```

Y necesito insertar esto en la consulta anterior y no se donde insertarlo para que se cumpla:

```
if ($customers['codigo_op'] == 'null'
```

Este es mi código completo:

```
<?php $customers_query_raw = "select ex.codigo_op, ep.entrega01_clave, ep.descripcion_articulo, ep.entrega01_envases, ep.entrega01_importe from " . TABLE_EXPORT_PATRIMONIO . " ep left join " . TABLE_EXPORT_COMPARATIVA_PATRI . " ex on ex.clave_patri = ep.entrega01_clave where ep.entrega01_envases <> '' and ep.num_envases <> '0' and ep.entrega01_indicaciones = '' and ex.codigo_op = ''";
    $customers_query = tep_db_query($customers_query_raw);

    while ($customers = tep_db_fetch_array($customers_query)) {
    if ($customers['codigo_op'] == '')  { ?>
    <td class="pageHeading_red_peque">Indicación!</td>
    <td><?php echo $customers['entrega01_clave']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $customers['descripcion_articulo']; ?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $customers['entrega01_envases']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $customers['entrega01_indicaciones']; ?></td>
    <?php } ?>
```

a este código necesito agregarle un count de este resultado.

```
//TABLE_EXPORT_PATRIMONIO
| entrega01_clave | entrega01_envases | entrega01_indicaciones  |
| xx.xx.xx.xx.xx  | 20                | blanco          |
| yy.yy.yy.yy.yy  | 30                |             |
| zz.zz.zz.zz.zz  | 0                 |             |

//TABLE_EXPORT_COMPARATIVA_PATRI
| clave_patri    | codigo_op |
| xx.xx.xx.xx.xx |   aaaaa   |
| yy.yy.yy.yy.yy |           |
| zz.zz.zz.zz.zz |   ccccc   |
```

lo del contador es: de este query:

```
$customers_query_raw = "select ex.codigo_op, ep.entrega01_clave, ep.descripcion_articulo, ep.entrega01_envases, ep.entrega01_importe from " . TABLE_EXPORT_PATRIMONIO . " ep left join " . TABLE_EXPORT_COMPARATIVA_PATRI . " ex on ex.clave_patri = ep.entrega01_clave where ep.entrega01_envases <> '' and ep.num_envases <> '0' and ep.entrega01_indicaciones = 'null'";
```

contar cuantos usuarios tienen `ex.codigo_op` = Vacio

Comment: listo ya edite la pregunta

Comment: ¿Quieres buscar aquellos registros cuyo atributo codigo_op es nulo o que ese atributo sea igual a la cadena null, o que sea igual a una cadena vacía o todos los casos?

Comment: si justamente eso cuando entrega01_clave de TABLE_EXPORT_PATRIMONIO  la comparo con clave_patri de TABLE_EXPORT_COMPARATIVA_PATRI y no encuentro el codigo correspondiente a codigo_op muestrame los resultados, fijate de hecho sirve el query pero en el while tengo que agregar un if para que lo realice, y estra perfecto, pero tengo que meter ese if: [if ($customers['codigo_op'] == '')  {]dentro del query eso es todo, este if detecta los valores que no existen.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien la última parte donde solicitas "a este código necesito agregarle un COUNT de este resultado". ¿Podrías proporcionar el esquema de la tabla? Me parece que la parte de `ep.entrega01_indicaciones = 'null'` podría ser errónea.

Comment: Lo siento, en la última edición no has proporcionado el esquema de la tabla, has hecho un resumen de las columnas. El esquema (scheme) es el SQL que necesitas para generar la tabla. Puedes conseguir el esquema con alguna herramienta como phpmyadmin o con el siguiente código SQL: `SHOW CREATE TABLE TABLE_EXPORT_PATRIMONIO`. La definición de `Vacío` que usas es ambigua. No es lo mismo una cadena vacía o un valor 0 que un valor `NULL`. No tengo claro si quieres detectar valores `NULL` reales o contenido de texto `null` o cadenas vacías como pones (si usáramos `===`) en tu código.

Comment: ahora si esta la tabla editada